# Property can't be found on ViewModel in UWP app

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

An Order form in UWP using Template 10 adds products to an order. The error is

`Invalid binding path 'OrderViewModel.FindProduct_TextChanged' : Property 'OrderViewModel' can't be found on type 'ProductViewModel'`

The relevant xaml snippet is

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainPageViewModel x:Name="OrderViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<GridView  ItemsSource="{x:Bind OrderViewModel.Products, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="ViewModels:ProductViewModel" >
            <AutoSuggestBox 
                Name="ProductAutoSuggestBox" 
                TextMemberPath="{x:Bind ItemCode, Mode=TwoWay}"
                TextChanged="{x:Bind OrderViewModel.FindProduct_TextChanged}">
            </AutoSuggestBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

The relevant snippet from the OrderViewModel and the ProductViewModel

```
namespace ViewModels
{    
    public class OrderViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

        public void FindProduct_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        { ... }
    }

    public class ProductViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        string _ItemCode = default(string);
        public string ItemCode { get { return _ItemCode; } set { Set(ref _ItemCode, value); } }

        public ProductViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

How to I correctly reference `FindProduct_TextChanged` on the `OrderViewModel` from the DataTemplate for the GridView which references `ProductViewModel`?

Comment: You use `OrderViewModel.Products` as the ItemsSource, that means the `x:DataType` must be `Product` and the `FindProduct_TextChanged` method must put in it.

Comment: Thank you @tao. I'm not quite sure what you mean. `Product` is not a member of `OrderViewModel` but `Products` is a member of `OrderViewModel`. `FindProduct_TextChanged` updates `OrderViewModel.Products` so I can't see how I can put it anywhere other than `OrderViewModel`. Or have I misunderstood? Could you provide a code snippet to illustrate what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voted up to @tao's comment. @Vague, I think you may misunderstand what `x:DataType` is used for. You can refer to the "DataTemplate and x:DataType" part of [Data binding in depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> When using {x:Bind} in a data template, so that its bindings can be validated (and efficient code generated for them) at compile-time, the DataTemplate needs to declare the type of its data object using x:DataType.

For your scenario, from your code `public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>();`, the type of your `DataTemplate`'s data object should be your `Product` class, not your `ProductViewModel`, and in the meanwhile, your `FindProduct_TextChanged` event must be find in this `Product` class, that means your code of  `FindProduct_TextChanged` should be placed in your `Product` data model.

By the way, I think there is no need to use `TwoWay` binding for `ItemsSource`. For this scenario, the binding target is `ItemsSource` of `GridView`, the binding source is `ObservableCollection<Product> Products`, I understand you want to update `GridView` when your collection is updated, this is work is done with [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx). Besides, only the binding source here can be changed to notify the binding target, so `OneWay` binding is enough. But it's not a big problem with your code.

So for your `GridView`, it should be something like this:

```
<GridView  ItemsSource="{x:Bind OrderViewModel.Products, Mode=OneWay}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:Product" >
            <AutoSuggestBox 
                Name="ProductAutoSuggestBox" 
                TextMemberPath="{x:Bind ItemCode, Mode=TwoWay}"
                TextChanged="{x:Bind FindProduct_TextChanged}">
            </AutoSuggestBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Thank you @Grace Feng - MSFT. Are you saying `FindProduct_TextChanged` should be on the `Products` class? If so maybe I should have `ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel>();` then `x:DataType="Models:ProductViewModel"` and put `FindProduct_TextChanged` on `ProductViewModel`. Does that sound like a better approach?

        `

Comment: @Vague, yes, if you insist to use `ProductViewModel` as your data model, then you're right. But usually we need to use data model here, not a view model.

Comment: Thank you @Grace Feng - MSFT. I didn't think it was good practice to pollute the model with functionality `FindProduct_TextChanged` as that is specific to the view. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Vahue, Normally yes, but it's important that your `FindProduct_TextChanged` is for the control inside of `DataTemplate`, when controls be placed in `DataTemplate`, they actually becomes a model for each item, not a real control, this is why we cannot direct access them by using their name. And usually we use `Command` for handling event in data model if it is allowed. There are a bunch of discussion about this, you can google them.

Answer (score 0):

if error is kind of like this I approved its a charset support bug:
Error       Invalid binding path 'XX.YY' : Property 'ZZ' can't be found on type 'CCC'

Either xaml and C# supports unicode; 
its because you use a non-ascii character in class properties. this is a bug I found today. Just rename your class proprty characters to ascii standards. Hope it will be fixed.